# How to retrieve data from database using AJAX based on a select tag?

Tags: php, ajax, web-services

Let's imagine we have two select tags

```
<select id='combobox_1'>
   <option value='1'>Description of fist record</option>
   <option value='2'>Description of second record</option>
</select>

<select id='combobox_2'></select>
```

And two tables on database

***table_1***

combox_1_db_id PK

combox_1_db_description

***table_2***

combox_2_db_id PK

combox_1_db_id FK

combox_2_db_description

Now i want to send an AJAX request to PHP with the value of the option selected in combobox_1 to fill with records from the database the combobox_2 based on the combobox_1_id.

JS

```
$('#combobox_1').on('change', function() {
  var option_value = $('#combobox_1').find('option:selected').val();

   $.ajax({
    url: '/get_records',
     method: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {   
        $(data).each(function() {
            var option = $('<option />');
             option.attr('value', 
             this.combox_2_id).text(this.combox_2_description); 
             $('#combobox_2').append(option);
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error on loading records');
    }
});
});
```

PHP

```
 $this->router->get_request('/get_records', function() {
        $records= $this->soap_server->getRecords(array(
            'combox1Id' => $_GET['combox_1_id']
        ));
        echo json_encode($records->return);
 });
```

But i don't find a way to send the id to PHP so i can get the records based on that id and load them in combobox_2, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the option_value in the ajax, just include it as data like this...

```
$('#combobox_1').on('change', function() {

// get the id of the selected option
var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

$.ajax({
    url: '/get_records',
     method: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     data: {combox_1_id: id},  // send the id in the request
    success: function(data) {   
        $(data).each(function() {
            var option = $('<option />');
             option.attr('value', 
             this.combox_2_id).text(this.combox_2_description); 
             $('#combobox_2').append(option);
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error on loading records');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't set the variable in php, it works if i do it like this             http://localhost:xxxx/get_records?combobox_1_id=1 in the browser but not with AJAX